# How can i delete item from database? ASP.NET CORE 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this entity:

```
    public class SimpleTask
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser? User { get; set; } 
        
    }
```

also, i have SimpleTaskRepository with method delete:

```
public async Task Delete(SimpleTask entity)
        {
            context.SimpleTask.Remove(entity);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

and SimpleTaskService with method:

```
        public async Task DeleteTask(int id)
        {
            var item = taskRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
            if (item != null)
                await taskRepository.Delete(item);

        }
```

My dbContext code:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<SimpleTask> SimpleTask { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

        Database.EnsureCreated();

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    }
}
```

when i try to delete some task (SimpleTask), i got SQL exception in console:
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]

```
  Failed executing DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DELETE FROM [SimpleTask]
  WHERE [Id] = @p0;
  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

i think that it is why i have property ApplicationUser in my SimpleTask, but i don't know how to fix it

i tried to change my Repository, using try-catch, but unsuccessfully

```
public async Task Delete(SimpleTask entity)
{
    using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    try
    {
        context.SimpleTask.Remove(entity);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await transaction.RollbackAsync();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your code threw an error and execution stopped? If so, please post the entire exception stack.

Comment: no, execution didn't stop. it's just didn't delete task and continue working.

in my console(cmd) there were only sql exception
  Failed executing DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DELETE FROM [SimpleTask]
  WHERE [Id] = @p0;
  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

even when i used try-catch, no error was caught

Comment: There has got to be more to the error. Check the output of the console again. I find it hard to believe that it would just spit out a SQL statement without an actual error telling what went wrong.

Comment: @JuanR i tried to show:  https://youtu.be/q7zzbxIY8Yk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the video you posted, there is additional information about the error and it pertains to the transaction:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20205]

> An error occured using transaction

A quick gooling revealed this appears to be a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/391979/an-error-occured-using-transaction-(20205)). It has to do with the way the connection is managed when you use a transaction and async methods:

> You need to use _context.SaveChanges() instead of _context.SaveChangesAsynch. The reason for the error is because the transaction runs asynchronously. When you execute _context.SaveChanges(), the transaction occurs in a commit, and the database connection is not closed and reopened to save the changes.

It does beg the question though. EF saving methods already wrap your calls in a transaction and your method is atomic by design. Why use another transaction?

Either remove the transaction (recommended) or switch to `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: oh.... thank you very-very much!!!! I lost several hours due to this error. you helped me a lot!

Comment: @RodyaHjilz my pleasure. I am glad I was able to help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the part of the code that cause problem:

```cs
public async Task DeleteTask(int id)
{
    var item = taskRepository.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
    if (item != null)
    await taskRepository.Delete(item);
}
```

From your exception error message, the ID is not valid. Check the ID again.
`FirstOrDefault` will return a default instance of the object if it didn't find anything that match

One small note, you probably don't need `GetAll()`, just `FirstOrDefault`, or Find is enough

For more information on:

- FirstOrDefault: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-7.0
- Find: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=net-7.0

Comment: The default in this case would be `null` if there is no ID match. The `Delete` call would never execute so he would never see an error message.

Comment: Also, I think he is using `GetAll` because of his implementation of the repository pattern. He probably needs to add a `FirstOrDefault` method to his repository and use that instead. Otherwise, he may be potentially loading all the tasks and filtering in memory, depending on the implementation of `GetAll`.

Comment: Thank you for answer very much! but I checked ID and i think that it is OK. There are screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/FCvL53D

Comment: @JuanR no, the IDs are the same. i have attached the screenshots above

Comment: @RodyaHjilz I know. I was pointing that out. :-)

Comment: @JuanR my GetAll repository method returns IQueryable<SimpleTask>
 return context.SimpleTask.Include(x => x.User);

i don't know why i need to add FirstOrDefault in my Repository, instead of implementation in Services

Am I violating some programming principles?

Comment: @RodyaHjilz and how would I know that if you don't share your code? That's why I said "potentially" and "depending on the implementation of `GetAll`.